# Nonetype dataframe for loop on python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

When I try to create a new column in my df using a for loop, my dataframe becomes NoneType and I have the following error.

```
appended_data = []
    for stations in dfs:
        df = dfs[stations]
        df = df.resample('5min').size().to_frame(name = 'count')
        df['end_station'] = stations
        appended_data.append(df)
    appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data)
```

I have the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-197-5250e93af3d8> in <module>
      8     df = dfs[stations]
      9     df = df.resample('5min').size().to_frame(name = 'count')
---> 10     df['end_station'] = stations
     11     appended_data.append(df)
     12 appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really figure out the problem of the code above, but I was able to solve my problem using the insert function.

```
   appended_data = []
    for stations in dfs:
        df = dfs[stations]
        df = df.resample('5min').size().to_frame(name = 'count')
        df.insert(0,'end_station', stations)
        appended_data.append(df)
    appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data)
```